# Is it safe to use a static `Serilog.ILogger`

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). I want to write log entries with a `SourceContext` of the containing class.

Is it safe (including thread safe) to do this:

```
using Serilog;

...

class Foo
{
    private static readonly ILogger Log =
     Serilog.Log.ForContext<Foo>();

    /* Invoke Log.Debug(...) etc. in other methods */
}
```

[The documentation (linked) has a small example that adds the context within a method](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts), rather than creating one to share for the type as above. I'd rather not have to put the same boiler plate code into every method where I am logging. Empirically the above seems to work, but can anyone offer definitive guidance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, `ILogger`s in Serilog are always safe to use concurrently from multiple threads.